# How can I fix the problem that directly get value being processed @OnEvent in Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

There is too much logic in the API and the API is too slow to run, so I handle some of the logic with @OnEvent.

However, from the frontend, after running this API, they run @GET API immediately. In this case, the @OnEvent may not be updated before @GET API is executed. The user sees different data.

How deal these issues? If the API is slow, users complain about the speed of the API. Sometimes the values don't match when handled by @onEvent....

I'm wondering I should ask the frontend to slow down @GET API execution....

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more helpful if you can provide more code for context for us to understand and solve your issue.

Generally, I'd refrain from using @onEvent if the logic is aimed at high latency APIs , instead try to include the entire logic under one API call and restructure using functions (async/await), and add some loading logic for the frontend part for a better experience .

Good luck